# Parse Multiline String

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to take each line of text in a multiline string and attach it to a variable.

Here's the sample string of text I'm trying to parse:

John David Doe
Thu, 07 Nov 2016 07:22:19 -0500
RandomText

I want var x to be "John David Doe" and var y to be "Thu, 07 Nov 2016 07:22:19 -0500" and ignore any text after that. For the script, that text would be dynamic, so I don't necessarily want to match for "John David Doe" but rather for the 1st line and 2nd lines of text specifically. I'd also prefer that each line be their own variable and not an array because I want to pass them into an array later.

Comment: Each information you want is on a different line. Why you don't split your string by line?

Comment: Hi @dbr0wn11 and welcome to SO. Can you show us what you have tried and why that isn't working? Also. Is the list longer? Do you need line 1, 2, skip 3 and then line 4, and 5, skip 6, etc.

Comment: *"I'd also prefer that each line be their own variable and not an array because I want to pass them into an array later."*. So... not an array... but an array... later. *confusing*.

Comment: `let [name, date] = string.split("\n");`

Comment: So this is parsing text to be added into Google Sheets.

var str = "John David Doe\nThu, 07 Nov 2019 07:22:19 -0500\nRandomText\nMoreText";

var array = str.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);

sheet.appendRow(array);

that works great, but I get the other new lines of text, which I'm not looking for, and I need to add another variable to the appendRow command, which doesn't seem to want to take any additional arguments if I've already passed an array to it. If I pass an array to it with variables, ie: "sheet.appendRow([x,y,z]);" it works fine, but not appendRow(array,[y,z]).

Comment: So `sheet.appendRow(array.slice(0, 2).concat([y, z]))`, or after my previous suggestion `sheet.appendRow([name, date, y, z])`.

Comment: Thanks trincot. the let works great.

Comment: I actually used const instead of let, it seemed to work ok. Since let doesn't seem to work in Google Apps Script flavor of javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You should first put each line into an array using `Array.prototype.split()`. Then using the Destructuring assignment, you can assign the variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('p').innerText;
const txtArr = txt.split('\n');
let [x, y] = txtArr;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

```html
<p>John David Doe
  <br>Thu, 07 Nov 2016 07:22:19 -0500
  <br>Random Text
</p>
```